# Main Activity fails to start up due to PendingIntent Flag error

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm developing a system app, and when I attempt to start it up from the home screen in Android 31, it fails and an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` is thrown.  Here's what the stack trace looks like:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tech.[brand].[name]: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
        at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.getPendingIntent(ForceStopRunnable.java:285)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped(ForceStopRunnable.java:158)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.forceStopRunnable(ForceStopRunnable.java:185)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:103)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

The stack doesn't reach any of my source code and far as I know I'm not calling any intent in my code so far, pending or otherwise.  Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `androidx.work` in the stack trace is `WorkManager`. As per the [WorkManager 2.7.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.7.0-alpha02):

> Make PendingIntent mutability explicit, to fix a crash when targeting Android 12.

Therefore you should upgrade to the latest version, [WorkManager 2.7.1](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.7.1) by adding an explicit dependency on that latest version to the `dependencies` block of your `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1"
```

Comment: Mine was set to 2.6.0.  Just solved hours of hair pulling.  Total lifesaver!

Comment: I am using implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1" and app keep crashing on Samsung devices ..

Comment: My app was crashing on android emulators API 31+ without logging anything at all.  This fixed the problem.  Glad I found this.

Answer (score 0):

`PendingIntent` is a flag in API 21+ .So either you can set it like this:

```kotlin
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) { 
  PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
} 
else {
 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT 
}
```

**OR**

According to the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#pending-intent-mutability) , one should choose `FLAG_IMMUTABLE`. Use `FLAG_MUTABLE` in case if some functionality depends on the `PendingIntent`

```kotlin
val updatedPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
   applicationContext,
   NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE,
   updatedIntent,
   PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT // setting the mutability flag 
)
```